# How to Give title to the component in UIPickerview iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

i want to know that is it possible to give title to each component like i have given in pic here?...[Portrait mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywG9N.png)

i have set the labels by adding label as subview, but i also have to manage it in landscape mode so here it is...[landscape mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frPf4.png)

SO, My question is is possible to get the selected label's frame from particular component? i mean i can manage it without adding subviews so i can manage this label in all devices and in all orientation.

thanks !!!

Comment: Check my answer. The key is to use selectedRow function of UIPickerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to set the custom title for selected row.
As per [**selectedRow**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614369-selectedrow) function in UIPickerView, you are returned with the selected row in the component. So you don't need to worry about adding an extra label for that or handle orientation modes.
Try doing this (**title** is what you are currently displaying in each row):

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        switch component {
        case 0:
            if self.yourPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == row
            {
                return "\(title) Hour"
            }
            else
            {
                return title
            }
        case 1:
            if self.yourPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == row
            {
                return "\(title) Min"
            }
            else
            {
                return title
            }
        case 2:
            if self.yourPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2) == row
            {
                return "\(title) Sec"
            }
            else
            {
                return title
            }
        default:

            return ""
        }
    }
```

Then finally in `didSelectRow` :

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    // your code
    pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
}
```

Though this won't be the best way (I guess), but it is certainly better than placing a separate label and handling orientations.

Comment: i have tried this solution but it gives weird effect when scrolling up.

Comment: What kind of effect ?